# Copy row from a table of a word document and paste it to the end of a table in another word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

In the below code:
mWrdTbl is an object containing the table of the 1st word document
adWrdTbl is an object containing the table of the 2nd word document
(both documents are opened)

```
mWrdTbl.Rows(R).Range.Copy
adWrdTbl.Range.PasteAppendTable
```

The code works but the row is pasted at the top of the table (I need it at the end)

Edit:

I found a workaround (but I'm not satisfied):

```
mWrdTbl.Rows(R).Range.Copy
adWrdTbl.Rows.Add
adWrdTbl.Rows.Add
adWrdTbl.Rows(adWrdTbl.Rows.Count - 1).Range.PasteAppendTable
adWrdTbl.Rows(adWrdTbl.Rows.Count).Delete
adWrdTbl.Rows(adWrdTbl.Rows.Count).Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
Dim myRange As Word.Range
Set myRange = adWrdTbl.Range
myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
myRange.FormattedText = mWrdTbl.Range.Rows(R).Range.FormattedText
```

Comment: I used "adWrdTbl.Range.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd" between copy and paste and it worked.

Comment: My previous comment is wrong: your code works but I wasn't able to modify it to paste row with destination table formatting, could you please edit your answer.

Comment: Edit to change what?

Comment: I need pasted row in destination table formatting. With your code the pasted row retain the original formatting

Comment: Why do the two tables have a different format?  The simplest way to achieve what you want using the formatted test method is to define a style with the relevant formatting and then apply it to the row after pasting.

Comment: I solved using "mWrdTbl.Rows(R).Range.Copy" and "myRange.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)" in your code